# how to execute python script by sending data from php in windows?

Tags: python, nltk

how to execute python script by sending data from php in windows?
test.php

```
<?php
$hello = 'world';
$result = shell_exec('hy.py' . $hello);
echo "$result";
?>
hy.py
#!/Users/jonii/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/python
import cgi, cgitb
import sys
print("Content-type:text/html\n")
who = sys.argv[1]
print("Hello %s" % who)
```

Comment: you can run like in command line - `/fullpath/python hy.py some_argument` (and don't forget space between `hy.py` and argument because now you run `hy.pyworld` - without space).

Comment: what are you trying to say?

Comment: `'hy.py' . $hello` gives `hy.pyworld` so you forgot space - it should be `hy.py world`. But you may need `python` like in command line `shell_exec('/fullpath/python hy.py ' . $hello);`

Comment: ps. PHP script can be run in different folder so maybe you will need full path to `hy.py`

Comment: thanks. its now working!